# Why can i not access these Values outside of this for-loop?

Tags: c++, pointers, for-loop

I used a .txt file (which includes letters and numbers in each line) as input. I put these strings in a pointer array line by line and then removed all letters in a for-loop and put all values in a double array which was meant for later use in the main programm. It doesnt work though. The Values are only accessible inside  the loop if i try to get an output outside of the loop by using `cout << Values[0] << endl;` i get nothing as output.[image]

The array "Values" can be looked at if I use `cout << Values[i] << endl;` inside the for-loop but I can't access it at all outside of the loop. How can i change that? What cant i access the values?
I have tried relocating the values in a pointer array because i thought that would allow me to access these values outside the loop but it doesn't work.
I read that arrays and variables declared inside a loop arent accessible outside the loop. Here however i declared the double array outside the loop which is why it makes no sense to me that its not accessible outside of the loop.

(I'm well aware that this code is really clumsy... but it [almost] works)

It was just pointed out to me that i should upload the code itself instead of a picture of it. So here goes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream Projekt;                                        //Einlesen der Daten aus Quelldatei
    Projekt.open("Projekt_1.txt",ios::in);                  //
    char *val[100];                                         //Definition eines Pointer-Arrays
    val[0] = new char[100];                                 //
    int i = 0;                                              //
    while(Projekt.getline(val[i],100))                      //Befüllen des Pointer-Arrays mit den 
    {                                                       //einzelnen Zeilen der Quelldatei
        i++;                                                //
        val[i] = new char[100];                             //
    }                                                       //
    string Val;                                             //
    double Values[100];                                     //Zahlen werden als Double in diese Array gespeichert
    int Anz;
    int Steps;
    double Interv;
    double g;
    double x[100];
    double y[100];
    double vx[100];
    double vy[100];
    char a [53] = {' ','a', 'b', 'c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {                             // ^ Array a[53] zum löschen der Buchstaben aus der Quelldatei (looks stupid but if it works it aint stupid)
        Val.assign(val[i]);                                 //Werte aus dem Poiter-Array werden in das Val Array übertragen
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j <= 52; j++){             //for-Schleife zum entfernen aller Buchstaben
            Val.erase(remove(Val.begin(),Val.end(),a[j]), Val.end());
        }                                                   //
        const char* Help = Val.c_str();                     //"char" Val wird zu const char* Help
        Values[i] = atof(Help);                             //übertragung von cont char* Help zu Double in "Values"-Array
        Val.clear();
        cout << Values[i] << endl;
    }
```

Comment: @acraig5075 i added the code. Im really desperate for help at this point. I have no idea why my code doesnt work the way i want it to work. If you can help me please do i'd be very thankful for any help i can get.

Comment: "What cant i access the values?" - what does it mean? What does "cant access" mean? What happens when you try to access them?

Comment: *Why not What. When i try to use cout << Values [0] << endl; outside of the for-loop i just get nothing as output... it doesnt even display a 0 or anything... if i use cout << Values[i] << endl; inside the loop however it seems to have no problem displaying the right values in the right order as output.

Answer (score 1):

> outside of the for-loop i just get nothing as output... it doesnt even display a 0 or anything

That's because your program is simply crashing.

You declare 100 pointers here.

```
char *val[100];
```

You attempt to initialize those 100 pointers here.

```
while(Projekt.getline(val[i],100))
{
    i++;
    val[i] = new char[100];
}
```

If `Projekt.getline()` returns `true` more than 100 times, you are writing outside of your array.  That is Undefined Behavior.

If `Projekt.getline()` returns `true` fewer than 100 times, your code dereferences uninitialized pointers.  That is Undefined Behavior.

If you are accessing exactly 100 pointers, you must initialize exactly 100 pointers.

Comment: so if i set this number to the amount of values i have in that file im trying to read as input it should work? Is there no way to make it dynamic? Because i'll have to use this program on different input files which might have different amounts of values in them...

Comment: @P.W. you probably want to use a `std::vector`.  It is designed for the needs you are describing.

Comment: I figured out a way to make it dynamic... should have worked in theory... didnt actaully work though. I did it with vectors now and i should have done that from the beginning... its so much easier :) Thank you!